# Validate GridView with CheckBox (at least one checked) c# window application

Tags: c#

i am working on a c# window application. i am phasing an issue regarding on button save. How to Validate GridView with CheckBox (at least one checked) in c# windowform application on save button? kindly show with example

```
{
 //  var checkbox = Convert.ToBoolean(this.dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[0].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value);
   for (int i = 0; i < dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       var checkbox = Convert.ToBoolean(this.dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows[0].Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value);
       if)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Alteast Check one record to save");
       }
       else
       {
           proceed 
       }
    
   }
```

Comment: Your code is hard to read. Put 4 spaces in front of each line to format it please.

Comment: A `DataGridView` is not a `GridView`. That's why it has a different name.

Comment: its datagrdiview sir..kindly help me to validate user atleat select one checkbox of datagrdivew in c# windowform while saving data to database

Comment: sir question is validate datagriview chekbox on save button user atleast checked on checkbox to save data from gridview..if user not checked any checkbox then display a message to user check atleast one checkbox from grdivew to save data

Comment: plz any body help on it plzzzz

Answer (score 0):

Use foreach for better performance,

```
    string message = "Alteast Check one record to save";
    int i=0;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPurchaseOrder.Rows)
        {
            bool isSelected = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value);
            if (isSelected)
            {
                message  = "YES";
                i++;
            }
        }
    if(message!="YES")
          MessageBox.Show(message);
    else
          MessageBox.Show(i.ToString()+" Items Selected");
```